# React Native - Scrollview horizontal freeze

Tags: react-native, scrollview

[image]

previously in the unit column can only scroll horizontally per each floor/block and I want to scroll units horizontally together.

this is my code :

```
<ScrollView style={{ width: "55%" }} horizontal>
  <View style={styles.GridViewBlockStyle}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```